# Подключение CSS к HTML / NodeJS / ExpressJSs

Tags: css, node.js, style, node-modules

Пытался подключить style.css который лежит в папке express вместе с index.html.

В итоге не подключается, F12 > Sources там файла этого нет.
Прочитал множество статей и постов, но решения не нашел.

server.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/express/index.html'));
});

app.use('/', router);
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.listen(process.env.port || 1337);

console.log('Running at Port 1337');
```

Подключал стиль так:

```
<link href="express/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Структура проекта:
[image: Структура проека]

Answer (score 1):

Вообщем, до меня допёрло что строка `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));`
Определяла путь файлов страницы как public/файлы. А папка называлась express. Надо было просто переименовать express в public

Answer (score 0):

Если файл *style.css* лежит напрямую в папке *index.html* (что мы и видим), код

`<link href="express/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />`

заставляет искать папку "express" в папке с файлами *index* и *style*. Проще говоря, обращаться к файлу нужно напрямую, или сначала выйти из папки и зайти снова (что конечно же не имеет никакого смысла).

Вот и ответ:

`<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />`

Comment: Нет, абсолютно так же не может найти